# How to enforce no eye comfort shield for certain apps?

Tags: samsung-one-ui

I have a Samsung Galaxy A40 SM-A405FN/DS, set up in German. It has a functionality called "Eye comfort shield" to make colors less blue and warmer.

[image]
[image]

I like my screen with eye comfort shield on always, as it helps me to not be constantly swallowed in the virtual world and stay more grounded in the real world.

But I recently downloaded a great game (*I Love Hue*, for the curious) which heavily relies on hue distinctions. The eye comfort shield makes it all the harder.

Is there a way to specify that eye comfort should be off for specific apps ?

For those who don't know:  eye comfort shield removes some of the blue component of the color of every pixel on the screen, so that everything appears warmer. Blue light, which in the real world we get almost only from the sky during the day, acts a stimulus to stay awake (and then we feel naturally tired in the evening). Too much blue light from a phone screen is supposed to keep the user awake and hinder falling asleep.
[One possible source](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/blue-light-has-a-dark-side).

This feature might be known as Night mode or Dark mode or [Night Light](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/night-light) in non-Samsung devices.

Images :

[image]
[image]

EDIT : @Firelord My attempts with Tasker :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When Eye Comfort Shield (ECS) is enabled could you try running this adb command `adb shell settings put system blue_light_filter 0` and see if it disables ECS or not.

Comment: Yes it works, including while having the app open. I can't wait to see what you're suggesting with that !

Comment: Setup Tasker app (trial version [here](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html)). Within Tasker setup Profile: Application -> select the apps where you want ECS to be turned off; create/assign a task having this action: Setting -> Custom Setting -> Type: System, Name: blue_light_filter, Value: 0. Leave rest of the entries as is. Save the task, enable ECS and now try opening one of the target apps to see if ECS turns off or not.

Comment: Excellent ! But no results yet ... see my screenshots in edit.

Comment: On that second screenshot, there is Play (rightward arrow) button on the bottom left. Upon pressing that Play button does ECS turns off or does Tasker report some error?

Comment: A notification appears : "Can't modify settings : Please click here to install the 'Tasker Settings' app to change the 'blue_light_filter' setting". It also independently started telling me this when opening the app (so somehow I hadn't correctly applied the rule or whatever).

Comment: And sadly when I click on the notification, it takes me to the page of the Tasker Settings app on Google Play, where it says : This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android."

Comment: Re: Tasker Settings app, try downloading from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/joaomgcd/TaskerSettings/releases).

Comment: Yup works. It keeps telling me that it might not work properly at all because it's meant for an older Android version but okay. Now the whole setup works : a few seconds after opening my app I get the ECS off. How about part 2 now, turning it back on when I quit this app or switch app ?

Comment: Found how to do this. You can add an context like for the other task, except you press the "Invert" button and then context is "Not <app>" and it does what you think it does.

Comment: If you post a summary I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Charles I think you're in a position to provide a working answer with nice screenshots and gotchas that you encountered. Go ahead. :)

Comment: That does not take into account my legendary sloth.

Comment: Also, the trigger seems to go through every time in reasonable time (and in fact the ECS button shows that its off) BUT the EFFECT of ECS is often still present ! And vice-versa. I think it is either a bug in Android, a delay (my phone can be slow), or we are missing a "refresh" sort of command or something.